# How can i manage this request?

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching, filesystems

Help me how could i manage this problem.

I have booking system which have 50000 registered hotels. And i want to send recently created booking information to each and every hotels. For receiving response of hotels for particular booking. If hotel can't give response for particular booking in given time period than i send it again after 5 minutes. So suggest me where can i store this sending data And recieving response of hotels store in database. So suggest me how can i manage this process. Where can i store this sending data.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: one Booking information to all the hotels or to the respective hotel.....

Comment: Booking Information to All the Hotels not the Respective Now

Comment: Create a response table with booking id, hotel_id and response...

Comment: Ok if i am creating response table than how many number of entries for single request send save

Comment: i also have response table but how can i set request in table or whatever?

Comment: Booking is just one... But the response is many. Right? Have a separate table for booking. Using this booking id, Store the responses in response table. Out of 50k hotels, some number of hotels might have responded in a desired period. You can send reminders who have not responded for a booking id

Comment: I am saying that i send notification and this send data for 50K hotels stored in database or cache or filesystem?

Comment: This 50k notification stored in database, cache and file system?

Comment: Why do you want to store a same notification which was sent to 50k hotels

Comment: Since we cant chat here..... chat with me at indrakumar.mdu@gmail.com

Comment: Last one please help me is this any way to store this sent notification for every booking to this 50k hotels please tell me i am not using email so please tell me other way to use.

Comment: Storing 50k notifications in any method in a single shot will hog the resources of hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to log your sent notifications would be

Try this as test method

```
    <?php
    echo date('H:i:s')."<br>";
    $data="";
    for ($x=0; $x<=50000; $x++) {
     $data .= "Notified Hotel ".$x."And here comes The data you want to track  \n";
    }
    file_put_contents('Logger.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
    echo date('H:i:s');
    ?>
```

This will do the job in milli seconds
For each booking id, you can have one txt file with 50k rows.